Azure Devops Project Migration
I have few organizations that I am about to close in Azure DevOps Service's, So i would like to migrate few of the projects to another Organizations in a different Azure DevOps Service. I was not able to find any document if this is possible or not(Migration of projects from Azure DevOps services to another Azure DevOps Services). Can anyone let help me know if this is possible and if yes any supporting document links is really helpful.
Thankyou in Advance.
Tried browsing the internet for possibilities

Azure DevOps does not have a built-in function to do this task, but there are several tools available that can do the migration.

Migration Tools for Azure DevOps -
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration

Canarys Copy Project - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.vstscopyproject



Thanks for the suggestions, will have a look at the suggested options and let you know. Thanks again
